# Safecracker and Categories

Tags: safecracker

The safecracker form related custom fields are being submitted, the problem is the select drop-down categories. After having chosen the category to associate the entry with, the respective category does not remain selected in the CP.

I'm using the [User Guide Code](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#categories)

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories">
{categories}
<option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
{/categories}
</select>
```

Comment: To clarify - you submit the entry via Safecracker, but when you view the same entry in the CP, no categories are selected (but all other data is there)?

Comment: Hi Derek, exactly, that's the issue.

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the template to http://www.pastie.org?

Comment: Hi Anna, here is it http://pastie.org/6317924 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and seems tot work correctly (EE 2.5.5). if you want to preserve already selected categories, you could make your select a multi-select.

```
<select name="category[]" id="categories" multiple="multiple">
...
</select>
```